# GetOpenFileNameW in VBA?

Tags: string, vba, unicode, getopenfilename

Okay, I may be way off base here, but what I would like to do is use the wide (Unicode) version of the API call for GetOpenFileName to return a list of multiple files.

Now, the reason I want to do this is: 
When selecting multiple files, the total character limit for the file names depends on the version of the function.
•ANSI: 32k limit
•Unicode: no restriction

Returning a large selection of files from a directory buried deep in my network can quickly exceed the ANSI 32k character limit.

So, what I've done is take my working ANSI declared function, and replace all `string` declared variables with `lngptr`.  Then where I need to assign values to these, I have used the `StrPtr()` function to convert the string values.

Now, when I try to call this function when it gets to the part where it calls the Declared function `lReturn = GetOpenFileNameU(OpenFile)` it doesn't actually do anything!.  No errors, nothing - just steps right past that line and nothing happens.  What did I do wrong??

This is where I am at now:

```
Option Explicit
'***NOTE: _
    This class object requires the following references: _
        <NONE>

'Declare the windows API function for GetOpenFileNameA
'MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetOpenFileNameU Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameW" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

Public Const OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT As Long = &H200
Public Const OFN_CREATEPROMPT As Long = &H2000
Public Const OFN_ENABLEHOOK As Long = &H20
Public Const OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE As Long = &H40
Public Const OFN_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE As Long = &H80
Public Const OFN_EXPLORER As Long = &H80000
Public Const OFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT As Long = &H400
Public Const OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST As Long = &H1000
Public Const OFN_HIDEREADONLY As Long = &H4
Public Const OFN_LONGNAMES As Long = &H200000
Public Const OFN_NOCHANGEDIR As Long = &H8
Public Const OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS As Long = &H100000
Public Const OFN_NOLONGNAMES As Long = &H40000
Public Const OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON As Long = &H20000
Public Const OFN_NOREADONLYRETURN As Long = &H8000& '*see comments
Public Const OFN_NOTESTFILECREATE As Long = &H10000
Public Const OFN_NOVALIDATE As Long = &H100
Public Const OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT As Long = &H2
Public Const OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST As Long = &H800
Public Const OFN_READONLY As Long = &H1
Public Const OFN_SHAREAWARE As Long = &H4000
Public Const OFN_SHAREFALLTHROUGH As Long = 2
Public Const OFN_SHAREWARN As Long = 0
Public Const OFN_SHARENOWARN As Long = 1
Public Const OFN_SHOWHELP As Long = &H10
Public Const OFN_ENABLESIZING As Long = &H800000
Public Const OFS_MAXPATHNAME As Long = 260

'Create a custom type that matches the OPENFILENAME structure
'MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx
Public Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As LongPtr
    hInstance As LongPtr
    lpstrFilter As LongPtr
    lpstrCustomFilter As LongPtr
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As LongPtr
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As LongPtr
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As LongPtr
    lpstrTitle As LongPtr
    flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As LongPtr
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As LongPtr
    lpTemplateName As LongPtr
End Type


'OFS_FILE_OPEN_FLAGS:
'Can view explanation of flags here on the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx
Public Const OFS_FILE_OPEN_FLAGS = _
                OFN_EXPLORER Or _
                OFN_LONGNAMES Or _
                OFN_CREATEPROMPT Or _
                OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS

'Windows version constants
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT As Long = 2
Private Const OSV_LENGTH As Long = 76
Private Const OSVEX_LENGTH As Long = 88
Public OSV_VERSION_LENGTH As Long

Public Const WM_INITDIALOG As Long = &H110
Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1


Public Function BrowseForFile(strTitle As String, myFilter As String, Optional initialDir As String = "") As String
'This function allows you to browse for files and returns a string containing the files selected

'Declare variables
    Dim OpenFile    As OPENFILENAME
    Dim lReturn     As Long
    Dim strFile     As String


'Set the file type filter
    OpenFile.lpstrFilter = StrPtr(myFilter)

'Set the filter index.  This is the order of the filters available to select from in the dialog.  1= the first in the list (and currently active)
    OpenFile.nFilterIndex = 1

'Set the handle to the window that owns the dialog box
    OpenFile.hwndOwner = 0

'lpstrFile is a pointer to a string which contains the current directory followed by list of file names selected. _
'Create an empty string to use as buffer, it needs to be at least 256 chars plus a terminating NULL char
    strFile = String(257, 0)
'Pass the buffer string to the pointer
    OpenFile.lpstrFile = StrPtr(strFile)

'The size of nMaxFile = the size, in characters, of the string pointed to by lpstrFile (less one NULL character at the end)
'The size of lStructSize = The length, in bytes, of the structure. Use size of (OPENFILENAME) for this parameter.

'BEFORE we can set the above two properties, we need to heck which version of VBA we are working with (SW uses VBA7, Office uses VBA6) _
 The # indiicates preprocessor command, which is processed prior to compilation, which ensures that the code compiles per the correct platform
        #If VBA7 Then
        'When environment is VBA7, use LenB (binary compare)
            OpenFile.nMaxFile = LenB(strFile) - 1
            OpenFile.lStructSize = LenB(strFile)
        #Else
        'When environment is anything else, use Len (text compare)
            OpenFile.nMaxFile = Len(strFile) - 1
            OpenFile.lStructSize = Len(strFile)
        #End If

'This points to a string containing just the file name and extension (without path info), whereas lpstrFile contains the path info also.
    OpenFile.lpstrFileTitle = OpenFile.lpstrFile
'This is to lpstrFileTile what nMaxFile is to lpstrFile
    OpenFile.nMaxFileTitle = OpenFile.nMaxFile

    'Check if the calling procedure specified a starting directory
        If initialDir <> "" Then OpenFile.lpstrInitialDir = StrPtr(StrConv(initialDir, vbUnicode))

'This will be the title of the window dialog, and is an argument that must be passed by the calling procedure
    OpenFile.lpstrTitle = StrPtr(StrConv(strTitle, vbUnicode))

'Flags control how the window looks and acts. _
'Can view explanation of flags here on the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx
    OpenFile.flags = OFS_FILE_OPEN_FLAGS + OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT

'Call the windows API function we delcared and get the return when it completes.
    lReturn = GetOpenFileNameU(OpenFile)

'Check the return, if 0 then no files selected or user cancelled
    If lReturn = 0 Then
        BrowseForFile = ""
    Else
    'lpstrFile contains the current directory followed by list of file names
        BrowseForFile = strFile
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current problem appears to be `OpenFile.lStructSize = LenB(strFile)`

Because you set strFile to 257, it contains 574 bytes. Based off the results, it looks like lStructSize will only work if it fits the file exactly, so you have to use your original `OpenFile.lStructSize = LenB(OpenFile)`

Also I don't think strptr works quite the way you use it, it converts a string to a pointer, but not vice versa

I wrote a function that converts pointers to string if that is indeed one of the problems. Unfortunately it requires you to pass in the length, I had a lot of trouble trying to get it from the pointer itself

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Function myConversion(lpstr As Long, lenStr As Integer) As String
    Dim bStr() As Byte
    On Error Resume Next

    If lenStr Then
        Dim lenBytes
        lenBytes = (lenStr) * 2
        ReDim bStr(0 To lenBytes - 1) As Byte
        Call CopyMemory(bStr(0), ByVal lpstr, lenBytes)

        Dim i
        Dim s As String
        For i = LBound(bStr) To UBound(bStr) Step 2
            s = s & Chr(bStr(i))
        Next i
    End If

    myConversion = s
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Alter!  
Changing that line from `OpenFile.lStructSize = LenB(strFile)` to `OpenFile.lStructSize = LenB(OpenFile) has it working!  
  
Not sure what you mean about StrPtr - I am only using it to convert a string to a pointer where I need to pass it to my function as such.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I copied an earlier version of your code. You had your function arguments listed as LongPtrs so I assumed you were trying to change them back into strings